# assignment of structure field values in loop - matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, structure, field, matlab-struct

I am trying to assign the field values of structure in loop.

Structure declaration with empty values:

```
result_struct = struct('a',{},'b',{},'c',{},'d',{})
```

I am assigning values in loop like that:

```
% assume a, b, c, d are variables in my workspace

% field names match with the variable names

for index=1:n

% some computation and store results in variables (a-d)

  result_struct(index).a = a;

  result_struct(index).b = b;

  result_struct(index).c = c;

  result_struct(index).d = d;

end
```

How can I assign the values to the fields using another loop? Like that:

```
for fname = fieldnames(result_struct)'

result_struct(index).fname = fname; % field names and variable names match

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use *dynamic field names* to assign to the struct (the leff-hand side). For the right hand side you *could* use `eval` but that is dangerous, so it's better to save your variable `fname` to a file and then load it back in as a `struct` prior to accessing `fname`, again using dynamic field names.

```
names = fieldnames(result_struct);    

for k = 1:numel(names)
    % Save variable to a file
    save('tmp.mat', names{k});        

    % Load it back into a struct
    tmp = load('tmp.mat', names{k});

    result_struct(index).(names{k}) = tmp.(names{k});
end
```

Alternately, you can use the `save` and `load` to just transform the entire thing into a struct without having to loop through the fields.

```
fields = fieldnames(result_struct);

% Save all relevant variables to a file
save('tmp.mat', fields{:});

% Load it back into the result_struct
result_struct(index) = orderfields(load('tmp.mat'), fields);
```

Comment: Hi Suever, thanks for the reply. Actually I got MATLAB error when I try 2nd method (without loop). The error says "Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures". When I load to new structure, it gets loaded without problem. What I observed is the order of the fields is different. Does it play a role?

Comment: This code works: clear all;
close all;

result_struct = struct('a',{},'b',{},'c',{},'d',{});
result_index = 1;
fields = fieldnames(result_struct)

for a = 1:3
    for b = 1:3
        c = a+b;
        d = a-b;
        save('tmp.mat', fields{:});
        result_struct(result_index) = load('tmp.mat');
        result_index = result_index + 1;
    end
end

result_table = struct2table(result_struct)

Comment: @asif Updated to ensure that the fields have the same ordering.

Comment: I think, the problem lies in the ordering of the variables. In my real example, I have defined structure with the following fields in this order: vin, fet_length, vout, iout, fsw, nfet_wide, ratio_width. And I get subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures error. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: matlab code gets extremely slow when file IO is involved --> understood, but the execuation time is in hours. I am generating 50k rows of data with 50 columns...